# How to use WebBrowser to obtain HttpOnly's Cookie?

Tags: c#, cookies, browser, httponly

I want to get through the WebBrowser login cookie and ultimately send the cookie to the `HttpWebRequest`. They `webBrowser1.Document.Cookie` get less than the `HttpOnly` that cookie. Way WebBrowser HttpOnly a cookie?

Development language is C#

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to get access to an HttpOnly cookie on the browser, I don't think you can as its more of a mechanism for the server, and the WHOLE POINT of HttpOnly is that it stops the client tampering with cookies.

So you can set them in your request but I dont think you can access them via the browser unless you can maybe get access to the underlying response which may contain it.